# Handling images using MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, image, upload, webserver

what are some best approaches for handling images on a web server using MVC3. Are there any best practices for this? By handling images, I mean enabling users to upload photos on a web server, saving them on the disk, and retrieving them when necessary to display on a page.

Answer (score 1):

Saving the images to disk with the path stored in a database is usually the best and fastest approach. Uploading can be handled by any regular means, but there a few good open source libraries to help you out ([plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) is the fullest featured I've used).

You can create you own `ActionResult` implementation and return and image to display. Your controller action can take whatever parameters you need to identify your image, you can then retrieve it from disk and return an `ImageResult` from your action.

Here is a basic implementation ([credit](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2008/05/aspnet-mvc-custom-actionresult.aspx)):

```
public class ImageResult : ActionResult 
{ 
    public ImageResult() { }
    public Image Image { get; set; } 
    public ImageFormat ImageFormat { get; set; }
    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) 
    { 
        // verify properties 
        if (Image == null) 
        { 
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Image"); 
        } 
        if (ImageFormat == null) 
        { 
            throw new ArgumentNullException("ImageFormat"); 
        }
        // output 
        context.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
        if (ImageFormat.Equals(ImageFormat.Bmp)) context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "image/bmp"; 
        if (ImageFormat.Equals(ImageFormat.Gif)) context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "image/gif"; 
        if (ImageFormat.Equals(ImageFormat.Icon)) context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "image/vnd.microsoft.icon"; 
        if (ImageFormat.Equals(ImageFormat.Jpeg)) context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"; 
        if (ImageFormat.Equals(ImageFormat.Png)) context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "image/png"; 
        if (ImageFormat.Equals(ImageFormat.Tiff)) context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "image/tiff"; 
        if (ImageFormat.Equals(ImageFormat.Wmf)) context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "image/wmf";
        Image.Save(context.HttpContext.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat); 
    } 
}
```